# How do I add HTML image slider into a asp.net c# Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, contentplaceholder

I have created an Image Slider using html with Jquery. I am trying to put this image slider into a contentplaceholder on my homepage which is running off a masterpage template with c#. It is not working.

Image Slider HTML:

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
     <title>jQuery Slider</title>

 <style type="text/css">
 .slider {
   width:1025px;
   height:500px;
   overflow:hidden;
   margin:30px auto;
 }
 .slider img{
   width:1025px;
   height:500px;
   display:none;
   margin:30px auto;
 }

  </style>
   <script type="text/javascript"
   src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript"
    src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-   ui.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

    function Slider() {
        $(".slider #1").fadeIn("fade, 500");
        $(".slider #1").delay(5500).hide("slide", { direction: 'left' }, 500);

        var sc = $(".slider img").size();
        var count = 2;

        setInterval(function (){
            $(".slider #" + count).show("slide",{direction:'right'}, 500);
            $(".slider #" + count).delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction:'left'}, 500);

            if(count == sc){
                count = 1;
            }else{
                count = count + 1;
              }
            }, 6500);
        }


  </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="Slider();">

  <div class="slider">
    <img id="1" src="Promotion1.png" border="0" alt="Promotion one" />
    <img id="2" src="Promotion2.png" border="0" alt="Promotion two" />
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Content Placeholder I am trying to put HTML into:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="ContentPlaceHolder1">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the relevant code, I do not see the code where you put the "control" into the ASP page (There is a content placeholder but nothing in it). Could you post that please?

Comment: You've posted two answers featuring follow-up questions, but we discourage that here. I've flagged them as 'Not An Answer', so a moderator will take a look at them.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a masterpage right that's why ur using a content page right ? You masterpage has already defined head / body and so on the HTML tags, so u need to just put the divs in the content place holder

```
 <div class="slider" onload="Slider()";>
 <img id="1" src="Promotion1.png" border="0" alt="Promotion one" />
 <img id="2" src="Promotion2.png" border="0" alt="Promotion two" />
 </div>
```

and your onload function call , you need to move your  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-   ui.min.js">
    tag into the masterpage and put your jS in a JS file and reference it inside your masterpage ideally, you could put your JS code in the content page but this is not good practice, it just easier to create the js file and plonk in a reference in your masterpage...good luck !

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, your CDN is wrong. it should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

notice you missed the https part. Then HTML for that single page should work by itself.

Then follow other suggestions using proper master and content tag, or comes back for more questiond :D

Comment: Nope regarding CDN! `src=//` is fine and is some ways is better. If the host page is http the resource will be grabbed with http; if the host page is served with https the resource will be served with https. No more annyoing mixed security context messages.

Comment: @Jon P, thanks for pointing that out, learned something new everyday! Just never saw that usage on any examples, and it happens not working with my local html file and complains that file not found from `file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. I guess that's the down side of it.

Comment: Ahhh that would be becaue your browseing direct to the html file, as opposed to a web browser... because in this instance you are using the `file` protocol (not http or https protocols), so it is attempting to retireve the jquery libraries using the same protocol as the html file.

Answer (score 0):

In a master page add the links to jquery, then add a content placeholder for the head.

Add a new page using the master page recently created. Add the function slider in that content placeholder. Remove the onload from the body and in the page use .load() using jquery to add the call.

Add a second place holder in the master to add content in the body and add your html for the slider.

Hope it helps.